# JavaScript constructor parameter or this.property

Tags: javascript, methods, parameters, constructor, properties

Can somebody explain the difference?

```
function Constr(name){
this.firstname=name;
this.log=function(){
console.log(this.firstname);}
}
```

And

```
function Constr(name){
this.firstname=name;
this.log=function(){
console.log(name);}
}
```

Is there a difference using the property or the argument?

Many Thankd

Greetings
KAT

Comment: Aside your question, you should throw your books to the trashes, and get something written after 2015. It's very exceptional to create a constructor function in modern JS, because we've had [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) since ES6, the current version is ES13.

Answer (score 0):

The local variable (constructor parameter) cannot be changed from outside. The property value can.

```
const obj = new Constr("a");
obj.log();
obj.firstname = "b";
obj.log();
```

Compare how the two versions behave differently in the above snippet. Btw, you also [should avoid creating methods in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/310870/1048572) but rather define them on the the prototype, which makes it impossible for them to access local variables from the constructor scope. See also [Javascript: Do I need to put this.var for every variable in an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13418669/1048572?javascript-do-i-need-to-put-this-var-for-every-variable-in-an-object).